# How can I let readonly user use "Alert me" function

Tags: alert

Because the "Alert Me" button is placed at the Ribbon bar, site visitors cannot see the "Alert me" button and cannot use this function. Anyway to allow visitors use Alert Me on document and library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Readonly user can click "..." > "..." > view property. User will be redirected to a page with the properties of item. On top of this page he or she will see "Alert me" button at ribbon.